# How to hide top panel in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

After last update at the top this panel emerged:
[image: panel on top]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In chrome go to **Settings** ->  **Appearance** -> deselect "*Use system style title bar and border*"

[image]